# How to replace characters in a big dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have a big dataframe with dimensions 42500 x 18500. I tried to replace some characters, but it is too big to use matrix. I would like to ask someone could help me with it. Thanks.
The following script is only working in a dataframe with small size (such as 42500 x 3000) in my computer.

> ```
>    geno <- read.table("datatable.txt",sep="\t", head=TRUE)
>    M <- as.matrix(geno[,c(3:dim(geno)[2])])        
>    M[M == "U"] <- "N"                  ## Replace "U" with "N"
>    H <- which(M == "H", arr.ind=TRUE)  ## Identify the Hs
>    M[H] <- geno[cbind(H[, "row"], 2)]    ## Replace with H values from "type" column
>    dat <- cbind(geno[1], M)
> ```

the data frame looks like as:

> ```
>    SNP_ID Type    Line1   Line2   Line3   Line4   Line5   Line6
>    SNP1   K   T   G   T   U   T   T
>    SNP2   M   A   U   A   A   H   C
>    SNP3   M   A   A   A   C   A   A
>    SNP4   K   T   H   T   G   T   T
>    SNP5   K   U   T   T   T   T   H
>    SNP6   M   A   U   A   A   C   A
> ```

when run the above script on the whole data frame, an error appeared as:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.0 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In structure(.Call(C_objectSize, x), class = "object_size") :
  Reached total allocation of 24573Mb: see help(memory.size)...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mutate_each_q` from the `dplyr` package to do this elegantly:

```
library(dplyr)
geno %>% mutate_each_q(funs(ifelse(.=="U","N",ifelse(.=="H",Type,.))),names(geno)[-(1:2)])
  SNP_ID Type Line1 Line2 Line3 Line4 Line5 Line6
1   SNP1    K     T     G     T     N     T     T
2   SNP2    M     A     N     A     A     M     C
3   SNP3    M     A     A     A     C     A     A
4   SNP4    K     T     K     T     G     T     T
5   SNP5    K     N     T     T     T     T     K
6   SNP6    M     A     N     A     A     C     A
```

Comment: After running 1.5 hrs an error occured: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 332 Kb
In addition: There were 28 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Error during wrapup: cannot allocate vector of size 332 Kb. warning message:1: In format.default(x[[i]], ..., justify = justify) :
  Reached total allocation of 24573Mb: see help(memory.size)

Comment: It looks like there are too many copies of your data being created and it is filling up your available memory. You might want to convert your data to a `data.table` and then run the command above. Otherwise, you will need to split the task into smaller chunks (eg 500 columns at a time) so the garbage collector can remove copies as it goes along.

Comment: make sure the convertion code is right: library(data.table)
     setattr(geno, 'class', c('data.table','data.frame'))

Comment: I would use `as.data.table`

Comment: I cannot find the function mutate_each_q from dplyr package. After finishing the code, how to save the changed data table to a csv file that can be inputed into other software. After convertion, it took only 40 mins to finish the character replacement.

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of dplyr, it was introduced in 0.2: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/releases/tag/v0.2.0. Save to csv using `write.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
d<-read.table(text="
SNP_ID  Type    Line1   Line2   Line3   Line4   Line5   Line6
    SNP1    K   T   G   T   U   T   T
    SNP2    M   A   U   A   A   H   C
    SNP3    M   A   A   A   C   A   A
    SNP4    K   T   H   T   G   T   T
    SNP5    K   U   T   T   T   T   H
    SNP6    M   A   U   A   A   C   A", header=TRUE, colClasses="character")

d[which(d[,1:dim(d)[2]] == "U", arr.ind=TRUE)] <- "N"
d[which(d[,1:dim(d)[2]] == "H", arr.ind=TRUE)] <- 
    d[which(d[,1:dim(d)[2]] == "H", arr.ind=TRUE)[,'row'], 'Type']
```

Output:

```
  SNP_ID Type Line1 Line2 Line3 Line4 Line5 Line6
1   SNP1    K     T     G     T     N     T     T
2   SNP2    M     A     N     A     A     M     C
3   SNP3    M     A     A     A     C     A     A
4   SNP4    K     T     K     T     G     T     T
5   SNP5    K     N     T     T     T     T     K
6   SNP6    M     A     N     A     A     C     A
```

Edit:  You may want to try importing your data as follows in order to make sure you are not reading in as factors, which could be using unnecessary memory:

```
d <- read.table("datatable.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE, colClasses="character")
```

Comment: @ Frank This code doesn't work for my data frame since it is too big.   Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.9 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  :
  Reached total allocation of 24573Mb: see help(memory.size)

Comment: @user3354212 OK, were you able to run the first line (i.e. `d[which(d[,1:dim(d)[2]] == "U", arr.ind=TRUE)] <- "N"`).  Also, you should let us know which line of your original code fails.

Comment: The first line of your code failed. d[which(d[,1:dim(d)[2]] == "U", arr.ind=TRUE)] <- "N"  where my orginial code failure depends on the size of dataframe I loaded. If I load the whole set it failed at M <- as.matrix(geno[,c(3:dim(d)[2])]). if I load a subset (i.e. 5000 columns, M <- as.matrix(geno[,c(3:5000)]),it failed at M[M == "U"] <- "N". if load in 4000 columns, it failed at changing H step. if load in 2000 columns it goes through no problem at all.